# Get HTTP request headers in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, http, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to get a specific header value from an HTTP request I made in Azure Logic Apps. The relevant logic looks like this:
[image]

What do I need to put into the 'value' field if I want to get one spefic header, say 'Set-Cookie'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you (as an example of getting `Content-Type`) ...

```
outputs('HTTP')['headers']?['Content-Type']
```

##### Variable

[image: Variable]

##### Result

[image: Result]

Comment: This did it, thank you! I just needed to replace the 'HTTP' with the name that I gave the step myself ('Get_OAuth2_Cookies' in this case) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to Code View and write,

```
@triggerOutputs()?['headers']?['Set-Cookie'].
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but that is not the solution. Please note that the green HTTP step is not the function trigger.